# Is that true that NASA sends their people to some Universities outside of USA in order to hire them?

Tags: nasa, education

I’m asking this because, I’m interested to know "does NASA send their people (workers: scientists and engineers) to some Universities outside the USA and not only in USA?" Because, right now I'm in high school grade 11 A in Anghel Salighy and now I’m heading to Airspace Engineer University. In Romania, the number of classes are 4 years only and after this I'll get to Airspace Engineer which only takes 3 years.

**Question:** I was wondering if it is true that every end of the 3rd year of University somebody from NASA will come to this University in order to see who will get hired?

After that somebody from NASA has arrived will then ask the teachers of the specific University to make an exam and test The who gets the highest grade? After they see who got the highest grade in exam will they take this student to NASA and this student will start his job without being tested in NASA?

**Q-2:** Will the somebody from NASA will hire that student according to where he/ she wants to be? Like, if a student wishes to become an airspace engineer and then they have passed the exam, then will the somebody hire them in NASA?

I don’t know if I asked in a wrong site, but if I asked in wrong site, please immigrate to a proper site. I don’t know if it is a stupid question, but I hope not, because my mother told me this and I want to know how will be at the end of University and I wish to know if it is true what she told me. I’m really interested to know this.

Comment: Have you asked at your university if recruiters from NASA visit?  At your university's career center or whatever it's called there?  However, it's extremely unlikely that NASA or its contractors recruit new graduates from universities outside the USA.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I’m not in University yet, I’m in high school grade 11 and I’m about to move this University

Comment: I'm sure they would be glad to answer your question even if you are not yet a student.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ok, I’ll see what I can do.

Comment: I think the scenario is very unrealistic NASA or whatever

Comment: The overwhelming majority of the astronauts or NASA employee are born U.S. citizens, who lived, studied and worked always in the USA. Beside that, the NASA is also a part of the U.S. army, and armies have an inherent preference to the people of their country.

Comment: Btw, if you are not an U.S. citizen, you would have a hard way to even find a way to get into the USA with a legal work visa. If you somehow get in, you will have a little bit better wage as in the EU, in exchange they make a slave from you. I have no hearth to rob your dream, but I think you won't be ever an astronaut. But you might become a scientist or engineer, working on a world where once being an astronaut is like being a commercial pilot. This is what the Humanity has now. Fix the world first!

Comment: @peterh, with all its issues, NASA is absolutely, 100%, not "part of the U.S. Army"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASA deals with aerospace technology, much of which is protected by [ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations). Specifically is the following paragraph:

> Defense services include the furnishing of assistance (including training) to a foreign person in the integration of a satellite or spacecraft to a launch vehicle, including both planning and onsite support, regardless of the jurisdiction, ownership, or origin of the satellite or spacecraft, or whether technical data is used. It also includes the furnishing of assistance (including training) to a foreign person in the launch failure analysis of a launch vehicle, regardless of the jurisdiction, ownership, or origin of the launch vehicle, or whether technical data is used.

NASA has to ensure that no information that is ITAR restricted is subject to foreign nationals. Bottom line is, it helps a lot to be either a US citizen, or a green card holder.

As to a specific university, I can't speak to the details. But it seems unlikely that NASA is going to recruit from a University an Aerospace engineer, when such personnel will have a difficult time achieving the US national status to qualify them to do technical work.

If I were you, I would look at ESA, which while they don't do as interesting of missions, you won't have the ITAR restrictions that working for NASA or any US based company would entail.

Comment: You pretty much need a green card or citizenship to work in any government agency in any technical capacity.

Comment: @CBredlow I have already a USA citizenship

Comment: That helps then quite a bit! I still wouldn't expect NASA to do a lot of recruiting from a foreign university, however. They don't seem to need to do a lot even in US universities.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto So this means, I have to show them a diploma that I have truly graduated University and then they’ll do some tests on me and they’ll hire me if I have passed all their tests? But, I’ll be really glad if they would do this because, it will be much easier for me to get hired, I don’t mean to be lazy, but just to find a shortcut, you know what I mean?

Comment: They usually don't do tests to hire a person, at least, not that I'm aware of. Just find a job you are interested in and apply for it, and do what they ask you to do.

Comment: "hey’ll hire me if I have passed all their tests" No.  They have to have an opening, and you have to be the best candidate for that opening.  FYI, it's virtually impossible to get hired by NASA as a new grad unless you have interned there while you were in college.  So if you want to work there, try to intern/co-op there.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Uff. Because, I saw a move about what kind of tests they make to recrutants, and if one of their recrutant fail one test, then he/ she is out, will not be accepted because they need someone who knows what they want to know and to be perfectly healthy so that to you won’t put in danger the entire mission. That’s what I learned. I meant, that when you passed their tests, then they’ll hire you, because they know you won’t put the entire mission in danger.

Comment: Are you talking about becoming an astronaut? Because that's not the same thing AT ALL as working for NASA in general.  If you're talking about becoming an astronaut, you need to edit your question and say that.  Also, best not to plan your career based on what you saw in a movie.  Far better to take advice from random strangers on the Internet :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I meant on working in ISS, because I want to have a career so that when they want to fix something outside from ISS, so that I can go there and also to stay in ISS for many months, I forgot how many.

Comment: Being an astronaut is very different, and does require tests... It would probably be worth asking another question. But even then, I would try to get some practical experience somewhere, working for an aerospace company or something.

Comment: The best way to check for an opening is to pretty much spam USAJobs

Comment: NASA most definitely does not go to colleges anywhere to recruit astronaut candidates.  They have never hired anyone right out of a college with no work experience as an astronaut candidate.  Their problem is wading through the flood of applications from qualified people who want to become astronauts.

Comment: who says ESA missions aren't as exciting? and which recent NASA missions don't carry ESA hardware :p

Comment: The OP kind of implied it. Besides, they don't do as many, and only manned via other partners (Although NASA has been in that boat for a while too, so...)

Comment: @OrganicMarble if for example, I have prepared for becoming an airspace engineer, then they’ll give test on things with math and I suppose on biology only?

Comment: Alex, this is not how hiring works *anywhere*. People aren't hired if they pass a test. They might need to pass a test when they are about to get hired after they applied for an open position. And they for back to you, because you're a promising applicant. There's no "I study this, then pass a test, then get hired" process anywhere I can think of.