# Does NASA use any type of office/groupware software and which is that?

Tags: software, operations

CERN for example uses MALT. What does NASA use where you need standard functions?

https://malt.web.cern.ch/malt/global/malt-table/

Specifically with *standard functions* I mean what you would use in any other office environment: write emails, letters, create and manage well searchable project documentation, manage spreadsheets for simple calculations/budgets where special data tools are not a requirement.

Comment: I don't work at NASA, but Microsoft Office is extremely common in the industry (and really the US as a whole), and I would be surprised if it wasn't the primary at NASA.

Comment: There's a lot of [in-house software](https://software.nasa.gov/) written by NASA (and this list is only the publically available stuff).

Comment: Are you asking about office automation stuff? @called2voyage is correct, they use MS Office for that, at least when I worked at JSC.  If you [edit] your question to add specifics, you might get an answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Looks like that is what he was talking about. He's edited now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about office software rather than space exploration.

Comment: @RussellBorogove We have had questions about ground work of space agencies not directly related to space before: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26021/58. That said, the question as currently framed seems low utility, it doesn't provide any context in which it would seem to be helpful info to someone working in space exploration.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97939/discussion-on-question-by-j-doe-does-nasa-use-any-type-of-office-groupware-soft).

Answer (score 12):

NASA's standard desktop office computer configuration is Windows 10 with Microsoft Office.  This software is provided agency-wide by the [NASA Shared Services Center](https://www.nssc.nasa.gov/) (NSSC). Here is an excerpt from the [NASA-STD-2804 Fall 2017 MINIMUM INTEROPERABILITY SOFTWARE SUITE](https://searchpub.nssc.nasa.gov/servlet/sm.web.Fetch/NASASTD2804_Fall_2017.pdf?rhid=1000&did=6056572&type=released) requirements document (the latest version available from the NSSC website to the general public).

[image]

It can vary. I worked for a time in a lab which used Linux office computers (managed by the lab itself), but the office computer setup most frequently encountered at NASA is a Win 10 / Microsoft setup managed by the NSSC.

Comment: Weird, don't know why I always just **assumed** NASA would be a Linux shop for a lot of stuff. Also didn't know what [ASCS meant](https://www.nasa.gov/offices/ocio/nac/ascs.html) or that [they're using a non-serviced Windows version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4346785/windows-10-version-1703-semi-annual-channel-end-of-servicing-on-octobe). Looks like NASA isn't too far off from my company on IT compliance :). Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The majority of NASA office space (at JSC anyway) is a regular office environment pretty much like any other. Maybe worse, there's nothing like dealing with a giant government bureaucracy when you needed to get some software that's not on the approved list installed.  They also had plenty of government approved spyware installed to slow your computer down. Working in that lab with the Linux boxes was far superior.

Comment: Unfortunately the included image shows that its information is now out of date

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's from 2017. Please post a newer one if you have it.

Comment: I don't, unforts - just a critique of the answer as is the purpose of comments :) A disclaimer might fit

Comment: It's the latest version available publicly.  I'll add that.

Comment: and to people screaming that this is way old software, I worked for several government agencies for another country that shan't be mentioned back in 2017 and they were still in the process of upgrading their IT infrastructure TO Windows 7 from XP.

Comment: It was also augmented somewhat recently by Office 365.